# InDesign: aligning a horizontal line to an exact coordinate

Tags: adobe-indesign, alignment

I am trying to put a Horizonal line at `Y: .9253` but cannot do it exactly by dragging it with the mouse. Is there a way I can punch in the exact Y value of the line's placement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the line and enter the position you want in the X or Y fields in the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen.

Comment: (or the bottom. Some of us are used to it there.) Apple-6 (on the Mac, so I guess either ctrl-6 or command-6 in Windows) will put you right into the X field.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum "Or the bottom" -- remnants of a QuarkXpress user. :)

Comment: Guilty as charged. Actually I started in PageMaker, and it was on the bottom there too, as I recall. I haven't worked in Quark in easily five years.